# Improve my block user system

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a basic system where users can block other users or stories.

The goal is that when a user blocks another user, it doesn't show the stories that the blocked user has created but the element blocked is a story, then other stories are seen but not the one blocked.

Here bellow I paste all the code that is doing the work:

**userModel.js**

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // Some other info stuff
  block: [{
    _id: false,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    story: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Story'
    },
    ts: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  }]
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

UserSchema.statics.getBlocked = function (user_id) {
  return this.findById(user_id)
    .select('block.user block.story')
    .exec();
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**storyModel.js**

```
var StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  anonymous: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
  // More stuff
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

StorySchema.methods = {
  filterAnonymousStory: function () {
    var data = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (data.anonymous === true) {
        data.user = undefined;
      }
      data.anonymous = undefined;
      resolve(data);
    });
  },
  filterBlocked: function (blocked) {
    var data = this, i;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (!blocked.block) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < blocked.block.length; i += 1) {
          if (typeof blocked.block[i].user !== "undefined" && JSON.stringify(blocked.block[i].user) === JSON.stringify(data.user._id)) {
            data = undefined;
          } else if (typeof blocked.block[i].story !== "undefined" && JSON.stringify(blocked.block[i].story) === JSON.stringify(data._id)) {
            data = undefined;
          }
        }
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  }
};

StorySchema.statics.getAllStories = function (blocked) {
  var i, promise = [];
  return this.find()
    .select('_id anonymous title user')
    .populate({
      path: 'user',
      select: '_id',
      model: 'User'
    })
    .sort('-created_at')
    .limit(200)
    .exec()
    .then(function (data) {
      var blockedPromises = [], anonymousPromises = [], i;

      if (!data) {
        throw new Error('There aren\'t stories');
      }

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        blockedPromises.push(data[i].filterBlocked(blocked));
      }

      return Promise.all(blockedPromises)
        .then(function (data) {
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
            if (data[i]) {
              anonymousPromises.push(data[i].filterAnonymousStory());
            } else {
              return Promise.resolve(data);
            }
          }
          return Promise.all(anonymousPromises);
        });
    });
};
```

So my questions are if there is another way of doing this much better or easier than what I've done.

As well, I'm open for tips & advices since I'm pretty new with `node` & `mongoDB`